# How to validate form in express validation 6 in node

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

This is my req.body data

```
{
  page_descriptions: '{"5a3a13238481824b077b23ca":{"language_id":"5a3a13238481824b077b23ca","title":"asdasdasd TTT","description":"ddddd"},"600eca59ced1c8317d473b54":{"language_id":"600eca59ced1c8317d473b54","title":"","description":""}}'
}
```

How to check the validation for title

Comment: I prefer to you use `joi` module for validation

Comment: Thank u @MohammadYaserAhmadi but can you please help in express-validation 6 for this validation